# Paid node checkout plus membership plans for a Drupal site

Tags: nodes

I need a solution to these problems for Drupal 7:

I need to create a website where people can post their classified ads. But the twist is that I don't want the ads to be published until the user has paid for it.

Also I need to create a membership plans per role (E.g. Gold Plan, Silver Plan, etc. for monthly subscription)

Now I have tried a few things like:

1. I tried using [lm_paypal](https://drupal.org/project/lm_paypal) for this purpose. But the issue with lm_paypal is that it does not publish the node after the payment has been made.
   The admin has to manually check the paypal IPN and publish the content if the node has been paid for. I do not know module development so I am not able to make these small tweaks.
2. I tried using [ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart) too but the standard issue rises again. The uc node checkout module is still in the dev version for drupal 7 and it works like hell. So many errors :(

So can anybody please come up with an alternate solution where I can achieve both the "Pay to publish" and "Membership plan" functionality on my Drupal 7 site?

Comment: Try using Rules, I think that's the only thing you need to use to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Being a great fan of [Drupal Commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce), I will suggest you to use it in your instance for this need.

You can use [Commerce Node Checkout](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_node_checkout) module for your pay to publish requirement.

For membership requirement, you can set product for each membership type & set [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) for it. Create rules on event completing checkout process & put some condition like - product SKU match to membership product SKU, current user type etc. & then add usertype to the user.

You will get many payment related modules with Commerce, so you don't have to worry about any ecommerce feature.